# Questions regarding math and programming

Tags: c++

I was computer science student in college,one of the courses was c++.
I enjoyed learning the native c++. i studied to pointers and classes and inheritance .

After that i took data structures, it was a nightmare(code implementation).
reasons are :
1-I'm not ready (i was careless back in school before college, my math skills were worse than you may think not because i tried but because i didn't try! i don't remember myself studying except the nights before the actual exams).
2-When i took data structures i realized computer science without any doubt is not for me(NOT EVEN CLOSE TO READY).

I have interest, even though i wasted years (2 exactly) feeling guilty for applying for CS.

am i a unique case or there are regular people like me who managed to succeed?
is it possible to excel even in my age 22 ? 
is it possible to be a good programmer after years of practicing?
is it possible to learn math to assist me on becoming a good developer in future years?

im now in cis major and it is way easier than CS and i could manage to pass, even though it is different than the one in your minds.

Comment: I always thought revision was a bad idea. Everything where I revised I failed, as a rule. You might point out that the reason I revised was because I needed to, and maybe I just didn't revise enough, but I degree - I think revising caused the problem ;-)

Comment: Is there a clear question in here? What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you that, yes you can become a good programmer with practice. But I'll also tell you that it's MUCH (much much) easier to practice something you like than something you don't like.
It seems to me that, it doesn't much matter what your GPA is or how well you did in school. If you like computers and computer programming enough, you can become successful at it.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you wish to do/accomplish and how dedicated you are. Maths will defenitely help you in certain areas of Computer Science, **but you can be a good programmer, and still be average at maths**.

*Always remeber that any talent can be improved on with dedication and practice.*

Comment: It's true if you want just to do things. But to be able to write a good algorithm (or even to see a simplier solution), math is very important. Try solving some problems on project euler without it..

Comment: Aggreed, but not all fields in programming will required good maths. And google is always your friend. Very seldomly will you be the first to face any given situation/problem.

Comment: Unfortunately google is good only when you have the keyword. Good thing SO exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Take math classes in college, they'll help with basic fundamentals that are used in CS classes.

Learning math by yourself will be quite difficult, especially if you're new to it. If your university provides the opportunity for formal math education (as an elective course or two), I'd recommend taking advantage of it. It'll help in the long run.

Comment: no available courses in there, but i think i'll get a private tutor. hope it's a good idea.

Comment: @user516935, private tutoring isn't something I'd recommend, unless it's for assistance with a math course. You're going to spend an awful lot on a private tutor if you expect him/her to teach you math fundamentals.

Comment: in my country there is no mercy in regard of this. i should only rely on myself, or wait 2 years to be sent to a decent college in a decent country, then i'll get to have access to remedial math courses (i believe this is what they are called).

Comment: @user516935, your university doesn't have any math courses? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: no they only offer higher math courses (linear algebra, discreet math,cal i&ii,computation theory, mathe for cs etc...)

Comment: @user516935, those are exactly the ones you want!

Answer (score 0):

While there is a lot of math in CS courses ( most CS depratments belong or once belonged to the maths faculty ) once you are out there in the field there is not much actual math done.

There are specific projects which require a lot of physics and math (oil field reserviour simulation, flight simulation, genome mapping) but these are actually quite rare.

There is another set of projects which require heavy statistics (stock market analysis, population analysis, drug trails etc.) which are more common but these projects want statistics graduates and not CS graduates.

So dont despair most programs in the real world don't require any maths more complex than

`if ((balance + sale_amt) > credit limit)`

Having said that data structures as in Linked Lists, Hash tables, balanced trees and graphs are probably the most useful part of your course; most of the other programming skills you can easily pick up as you go along but you really need to study these to be an effective programer.

Comment: game development? rendering? search? all math heavy, and not so rare.

Comment: also data compression, image processing, encryption, communications.

Comment: @Alex,@ruslik -- Most of the above have readily avaiable and well tested libraries to do the heavy lifting, or, in the case of search the heavyu math is concentrated in on company.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're going to do with a CS degree. Most of the actual math you will use as a general programmer is algebra I.  However, learning math well also requires you to learn other skills - like how to break a problem down into smaller parts, how to communicate correctly with math, and how to translate English descriptions into mathematical equations.

Comment: true so can you give guidelines, do you mean algorithm analysis and design? principles of SE ??